# Rails, How to render a view/partial in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my model I have:

```
after_create :push_create
```

I push_create I need to render a view. I'm trying to do that like so:

```
  def push_event(event_type)
    X["XXXXX-#{Rails.env}"].trigger(event_type, 
      {
        :content => render( :partial =>"feeds/feed_item", :locals => { :feed_item => self })
      }
    )
  end
```

This angers rails as it doesn't like me rendering a view in the model but I need it there.

Error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `render' for #<WallFeed:0x1039be070>):
```

Suggestions? Should I render it somewhere else somehow? Or how can I render in the model to set content? Thanks

Comment: this is a fundamentally wrong approach. Why not put the after filter in the controller ?

Comment: I'm using pusher app, so it goes in the model.

Comment: i don't really know what pusher is, but i don't see how a really bad programming practice relates to an application, to make it must use. Filters and rendering should always be handled by a controller.

Comment: Thanks so how can I render the controller from inside the model to store the result in a field?

Comment: Can you use a helper in a model?

Comment: you can use a helper where you want, as far as I know, but the rendering methods are defined on the controller, so a helper doesn't really buy you anything.

Comment: Whats in that 'feeds/feed_item' partial? What are you trying to send into that `:content` param?

Comment: For anyone coming from Google looking for the Rails 5 way of doing this, @olegafanasyev has the _built-in_ way to go [a little down the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318959/rails-how-to-render-a-view-partial-in-a-model#answer-42924760).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

## proper solution

Well, "they" are right. You really have to do the rendering in a controller -
but it's fair game to call that controller from a model! Fortunately, AbstractController
in Rails 3 makes it easier than I thought. I wound up making a simple
ActionPusher class, working just like ActionMailer. Perhaps I'll get ambitious and
make this a proper gem someday, but this should serve as a good start for anyone else in my shoes.

I got the most help from this link: http://www.amberbit.com/blog/2011/12/27/render-views-and-partials-outside-controllers-in-rails-3/

in lib/action_pusher.rb

```
class ActionPusher < AbstractController::Base
  include AbstractController::Rendering
  include AbstractController::Helpers
  include AbstractController::Translation
  include AbstractController::AssetPaths
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  helper ApplicationHelper
  self.view_paths = "app/views"

  class Pushable
    def initialize(channel, pushtext)
      @channel = channel
      @pushtext = pushtext
    end

    def push
      Pusher[@channel].trigger('rjs_push', @pushtext )
    end
  end
end
```

in app/pushers/users_pusher.rb.  I guess the require could go somewhere more global?

```
require 'action_pusher'

class UsersPusher < ActionPusher
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def channel
    @user.pusher_key
  end

  def add_notice(notice = nil)
    @notice = notice
    Pushable.new channel, render(template: 'users_pusher/add_notice')
  end
end
```

Now in my model, I can just do this:

```
after_commit :push_add_notice

private

def push_add_notice
  UsersPusher.new(user).add_notice(self).push
end
```

and then you'll want a partial, e.g. app/views/users_pusher/add_notice.js.haml, which could be as simple as:

```
alert('#{@notice.body}')
```

I guess you don't really need to do it with Pushable inner class and the .push
call at the end, but I wanted to make it look like ActiveMailer. I also have a
pusher_key method on my user model, to make a channel for each user - but this
is my first day with anything like Pusher, so I can't say for sure if that's the right
strategy.  There's more to be fleshed out, but this is enough for me to get started.

Good luck!

### (this was my first draft answer, leaving it in because it might help someone)

I've got the general outline of a solution working.  Like this, in your model:

```
after_create :push_new_message

private

def render_anywhere(partial, assigns = {})
  view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, assigns)
  view.extend ApplicationHelper
  view.render(:partial => partial)
end  

def push_new_message
  pushstring = render_anywhere('notices/push_new_message', :message_text => self.body)
  Pusher[user.pusher_key].trigger!('new_message', pushstring)
end
```

that is definitely working - the template is rendering, and gets eval()'ed on the client side successfully.  I'm planning to clean it up, almost certainly move render_anywhere somewhere more general, and probably try [something like this](http://facebooker.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/facebooker/lib/facebooker/rails/publisher.rb)

I can see that pushes will need their own templates, calling the generally available ones, and I may try to collect them all in one place.  One nice little problem is that I sometimes use controller_name in my partials, like to light up a menu item, but I'll obviously have to take a different tactic there. I'm guessing I might have to do something to get more helpers available, but I haven't gotten there yet.

Success! Hooray! This should answer your question, and mine - I'll add more detail if it seems appropriate later.  Good luck!!!!

#### original non-answer from an hour ago left for clarity

I don't have an answer, but this timely question deserves more clarification, and I'm hoping to get closer to *my* answer by helping ask :)

I'm facing the same problem.  To explain a little more clearly, Pusher asynchronously sends content to a connected user browser.  A typical use case would be a showing the user they have a new message from another user.  With Pusher, you can push a message to the receiver's browser, so they get an immediate notification if they are logged in.  For a really great demo of what Pusher can do, check out http://wordsquared.com/

You can send any data you like, such as a JSON hash to interpret how you like it, but it would be very convenient to send RJS, just like with any other ajax call and eval() it on the client side.  That way, you could (for example) render the template for your menu bar, updating it in its entirety, or just the new message count displayed to the user, using all the same partials to keep it bone-DRY.  In principle, you could render the partial from the *sender's* controller, but that doesn't make much sense either, and there might not even be a request, it could be triggered by a cron job, for example, or some other event, like a stock price change.  The sender controller just should not have to know about it - I like to keep my controllers on a starvation diet ;)

It might sound like a violation of MVC, but it's really not - and it really should be solved with something like ActionMailer, but sharing helpers and partials with the rest of the app.  I know in my app, I'd like to send a Pusher event at the same time as (or instead of) an ActionMailer call.  I want to render an arbitrary partial for user B based on an event from user A.

These links may point the way towards a solution:

- http://blog.choonkeat.com/weblog/2006/08/rails-calling-r.html
- [How to render a Partial from a Model in Rails 2.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003300/how-to-render-a-partial-from-a-model-in-rails-2-3-5)
- http://mattwindsurfs.wordpress.com/2008/06/19/rails-render-in-a-model/
- http://davetroy.blogspot.com/2008/02/actsasrenderer-brings-output-to-models.html
- https://github.com/asapnet/acts_as_renderer
- http://ethilien.net/archives/render-rails-templates-anywhere-even-in-a-model/

The last one looks the most promising, offering up this tantalizing snippet:

```
def render_anywhere(partial, assigns)
  view = ActionView::Base.new(Rails::Configuration.new.view_path, assigns)
  ActionView::Base.helper_modules.each { |helper| view.extend helper }
  view.extend ApplicationHelper
  view.render(:partial => partial)
end
```

As does [this link](http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/50) provided by another poster above.

I'll report back if I get something working

tl;dr: me too!

Comment: @agoragames - awesome work!  I also took this solution a step further by implementing an "ApplicationPusher" which is a application level base class for all my pusher controllers.  This adds in support for things like sessions(current_user) and authorization(via DeclarativeAuthorization): https://gist.github.com/synth/6170072

Comment: I'm using this solution now, and it works really great!

Comment: Just adding a note that the helpful url linked at the top of the comment has changed: http://www.amberbit.com/blog/2011/12/27/render-views-and-partials-outside-controllers-in-rails-3/ and also adding that I've found this one helpful: https://gist.github.com/juggy/977181

Comment: It is not absolutely necessary to have a controller. See my answer below.

Comment: `ApplicationController.new.render_to_string(partial: 'messages/any', ...)` is much better

Comment: rails 4.x solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263220/rendering-partials-view-in-a-rake-task-background-job-model-in-rails-4

Comment: Awesome! I have to log in to upvote this very detailed answer 

Answer (score 62):

I just do this:

```
ApplicationController.new.render_to_string(partial: 'messages/any', locals: { variable: 'value' })
```

Comment: For some reason, i couldn't use `link_to` in my partials with this solution. The error was `undefined method `host' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @Frexuz: I am passing the controller to the model method that calls render and use this one for calling the render_to_string method. Does that fix your problem?

Comment: `cache` throws `undefined method host' for nil:NilClass` too

Comment: I still use this, but have never been a fan of "link_to" - always kept my routing simple enough that it made more sense to either have each object know it's url (I define model.url in a superclass), so instead of link_to(@user), I use a href=@user.url - imo routing helpers was one of the huge areas rails went astray.  Ultimately, sorry, not sure why this would break it - you might try messing around with set_instance_variable('@controller', controller), but then you'd have to set a thread global to store controller + might as well do things "right" in the first place once it gets that ugly.

Comment: This worked for me:  `ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string` - without ApplicationController errors.

Comment: @PeterEhrlich did you manage to do that while extending ApplicationHelper?

Answer (score 48):

### Rails 5 way

In Rails 5 **rendering outside a controller** became pretty straightforward due to [implemented](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderer.html) `render` controller class method:

```
# render template
ApplicationController.render 'templates/name'
# render action
FooController.render :index
# render file
ApplicationController.render file: 'path'
# render inline
ApplicationController.render inline: 'erb content'
```

When calling `render` outside of a controller, one can assign instance variables via `assigns` option and use any other options available from within a controller:

```
ApplicationController.render(
  assigns: { article: Article.take },
  template: 'articles/show',
  layout: false
)
```

*Request environment* can be tailored either through default options

```
ApplicationController.render inline: '<%= users_url %>'
# => 'http://default_host.com/users'

ApplicationController.renderer.defaults[:http_host] = 'custom_host.org'
# => "custom_host.org"

ApplicationController.render inline: '<%= users_url %>'
# => 'http://custom_host.org/users'
```

or explicitly by initializing a new renderer

```
renderer = ApplicationController.renderer.new(
  http_host: 'custom_host.org',
  https: true
)
renderer.render inline: '<%= users_url %>'
# => 'https://custom_host.org/users'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get missing partial errors for this method because it looks inside 'app/views/application' for partials unless I render them using their full path. I have to <%= render '/things/mypartial' %> instead of just <%= render 'mypartial' %>. As an alternative I can use ThingsController.render but that seems kind of messy. Anyone know how to set the render path? #view_paths just points to /app/views so that's not it.

Comment: great answer. i wonder why my asset_host is example.org even tho i set `http_host: ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]`

Comment: Thanks for this, my code looked like this:    ```FooController.render('show', assigns: { users: users })```

Comment: Found this tutorial: https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/actioncontroller-renderer

Answer (score 25):

You can use ActionView directly and render partials to string without having a controller. I find that pattern useful to create models that encapsulate some javascript generation, for instance.

```
html = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths['app/views']).render(
  partial: 'test', 
  formats: [:html],
  handlers: [:erb],
  locals: { variable: 'value' }
)
```

Then, just put your `_test.html.erb` in you view folder and try it out!

Comment: Simple and easy, best answer

Comment: Hehe, I just googled this question myself. Thank you myself from the past!

Comment: Although I don't remember exactly how I did that, you just need to include the helpers in your ActionView::Base object

Comment: if you store the actionview base instance as "printer" you can do printer.extend(Rails.application.helpers)

Comment: I'm unable to add any locals to this object.

Answer (score 5):

Rails 6.0.0 compatible answer, since I ended up on this page while searching for a solution:

```rb
lookup_context = ActionView::LookupContext.new(Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"])
renderer = ActionView::Base.new(lookup_context)
renderer.extend(Rails.application.helpers)
renderer.render \
  template: "foo/bar",
  formats: [:html],
  handlers: [:erb],
  locals: { user: User.new }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure the answers you seek lie within [Crafting Rails Applications](http://plataformatec.com.br/crafting-rails-applications/) where **Jose Valim** goes into great detail about *how* and *why* you would want to render views straight from your db

Sorry I can't be of more help yet because I've just started reading it myself tonight.

You *might* find some help [here](http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/50) - it's a blog post about doing this sort of thing, albeit using different methods than yours

Answer (score 2):

the "proper" way to do this is to push an object in serialized form(json), and then have the view deal with it once the event is received.  Perhaps you want to use Handlebars to render the object.

Edit: I originally wrote about how, despite my answer, I was going to follow your example.  But I just realized there is a HUGE gotcha with your approach when it comes to push notifications.

In your problem, you are doing push notifications to one user.  For me, I was broadcasting out to a set of users.  So I was going to render html with a presumption of a "current_user" and all that comes with it(eg logic, permissions, etc).  This is NO BUENO as each push notification will be received by a different "current user".

Therefore, really, you need to just send back the data, and let each individual view handle it.

Comment: This isn't very dry unless you are using js to render all your templates.

Answer (score 0):

You should call all render methods from a controller. So, in this case, you can notify the controller that the object has been created and the controller can then render the view. Also, since you can render only once, I think you can wait for all your server side operations to complete before invoking the render.

Comment: Thanks how would I render with the controller and set it to content in the model as shown above?

Comment: Could you please update the question to be more specific about what you want to achieve? jaydel correctly points that this is not the Rails way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

The render methods are defined on the ActiveController class and its progeny. Inherently you do not have access to it on the model, nor is it a class method so you can't use it without an instance of the controller.

I've never tried to instantiate a controller for the express purpose of simply stringifying a partial, but if you can get your hands on a controller, render_to_string seems to be the way to go.

I will chime in by saying that if you're going down this path you're taking RoR "off the Rails". This is a violation of MVC and fundamentally poor program design.This doesn't mean I think you're a bad person :P Sometimes life drives us off the rails, so to speak.

I can't speak to the details that have driven you to do this, but I'd strongly suggest you rethink your approach.

Comment: thanks for the push back. I'm not sure how else to get this to work. I'm using the pusher gem(https://github.com/pusher/pusher-gem). Which triggers when the model has a new record added. It's there in the model where I want to push the new object out. Not sure how I can do that outside of the model?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a gist for this.
I needed something similar, where the models don't necessarily (or in my case, ever) get updated via a controller, so the logic can't sit there.

Created a server-push based controller:
https://gist.github.com/4707055