# Rails rendering json partial in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jbuilder

In our rails 3.2 app, we are using Jbuilder to render our json responses (nothing special here). The json view could be as simple as this:

_model_name.json.jbuilder

```
json.extract!(page, :id, :name, :url_name)
```

We often need to return a deeply nested json object, and Jbuilder partials work great for this:

_page.json.jbuilder

```
json.extract!(page, :id, :name, :url_name)
json.page_images (page_images) do |json, page_image|
    json.partial! page_image
end
```

The last example will retrieve the page, and nested page_images, json representation... again nothing special.

Often, a single partial will call another, and may return a nested json object 2 or 3 levels deep.

**PROBLEM**

Like I mentioned above, we use Jbuilder partials to quickly link multiple partials together to form a deeply nested json object for the view. We also need build these exact same nested objects as a hash (rather than json) AND make them available to a model.

It's simple to get a Jbuilder object to output a hash using the .attributes! method, but we're having some serious difficultes giving Jbuilder access to the view partials from a model.

Looking at the Jbuilder source, it looks like the JbuilderTemplate class needs access to the controller context to make everything work.

We might try something like this:

```
class SomeClass

  def initialize pages
    @pages = pages
    @context = ActionController::Base.new
  end

  def to_hash
     builder = JbuilderTemplate.new(@context)
     builder.pages(@pages) do |json, page|
        json.partial! page
     end
     builder.attributes!
  end
end
```

The example above is obviously incorrect, but it illustrates what needs to be done. I'm just not sure how to pass initialize a controller from a model, and then pass the controller context.

Some leads that we are following:

- [how-to-render-a-view-partial-in-a-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318959/rails-how-to-render-a-view-partial-in-a-model)
- [rendering-from-a-model-in-rails-3](http://wholemeal.co.nz/blog/2011/04/05/rendering-from-a-model-in-rails-3/)

Can anyone help point us in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a solution. We fell back to using as_json to configure our model json output.

Comment: Have a look at my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234018/rails-rendering-json-partial-in-model#answer-37977283) if you still want to be able to reuse your jbuilder templates.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you were on the right track here. You should be able to call `json.array!` and build the partial normally if you pass the block directly in the initializer.

```
def to_hash
  builder = JbuilderTemplate.new(@context) do |json|
    json.array! @pages, partial: 'path/to/partial'
  end
  builder.attributes!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ActiveModel::Serializer to do this exact same thing.  You can render the json in the model or whereever - we do this to pre-populate the cache.

The syntax for doing this wasn't initially obvious, so I'm posting here:

```
ItemSerializer.new(item).to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this functionality, I can show you some shim:

```
c = ActionController::Base.new
c.instance_variable_set '@item', Item.find(5)
JSON.parse c.render_to_string('items/show')
```