# Rendering partials / view in a rake task / background job / model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've read a lot on rendering Rails partials and views in rake tasks /  background jobs / models. The vast majority of things I have found on Stackoverflow and the web describe approaches working in Rails 3, but they seem outdated and I didn't get them to work (even with quite some time spent experimenting).

So, how can I **render a partial in a background job in Rails 4?**

Here's the best approach I've worked out so far (demonstrated in the console).

```
c = ApplicationController.new
result = c.render_to_string(partial: 'tweets/tweet', locals: {tweet: Tweet.first})
# =>
#   Tweet Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "tweets".* FROM "tweets" ORDER BY "tweets"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
#   Author Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "authors"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
#   Status Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "statuses".* FROM "statuses" WHERE "statuses"."twitter_id" = 367523226848866304 LIMIT 1
#   Rendered tweets/_tweet_body.html.slim (17.5ms)
#   Rendered tweets/_resolved_tweet.html.slim (23.7ms)
#   Rendered tweets/_tweet.html.slim (28.1ms)
# ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `tweet_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb21bf797a0>:0x007fb21cb009e8>
# from /Users/thomasklemm/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:129:in `polymorphic_url'
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

*Update*: The `tweet_path` mentioned above is indeed not defined. This error resulted from linking to a path `= link_to 'Tweet', [@project, tweet]` (slim templates) using an instance variable that would be present in views inheriting from a certain controller, but not when rendered outside of this context. I solved this going through the appropriate association instead `= link_to 'Tweet', [tweet.project, tweet]`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's what I compiled from lots of sources and what works for me in Rails 4.

With this Renderer class, you should be able to render Rails 4 views and partials in any context, like background jobs, service objects, models, workers, you name it.

```
# app/services/renderer.rb
# Render views and partials in rake tasks,
# background workers, service objects and more
#
# Use:
#
# class MyService
#   def render_stuff
#     result = renderer.render(partial: 'tweets/tweet', locals: {tweet: Tweet.first})
#     # or even
#     result = renderer.render(Tweet.first)
#   end
#
#   private
#
#   def renderer
#     @renderer ||= Renderer.new.renderer
#   end
# end
#
class Renderer
  def renderer
    controller = ApplicationController.new
    controller.request = ActionDispatch::TestRequest.new
    ViewRenderer.new(Rails.root.join('app', 'views'), {}, controller)
  end
end

# app/services/view_renderer.rb
# A helper class for Renderer
class ViewRenderer < ActionView::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include ApplicationHelper

  def default_url_options
     {host: Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]}
  end
end
```

**Update**:

There seems to be an easier solution: http://makandracards.com/makandra/17751-render-a-view-from-a-model-in-rails

```
ApplicationController.new.render_to_string(
  :template => 'users/index',
  :locals => { :@users => @users }
)
# Mind the weird syntax to set @ variables in :locals.
```

**Update 2**:

There's a gem called [`render_anywhere`](https://github.com/yappbox/render_anywhere) that allows for calling "render" from anywhere: models, background jobs, rake tasks, etc.

**Update 3**:

In **Rails 5**, the renderer has been extracted and can be used standalone from background jobs and other places:

```
ApplicationController.renderer.render(
  partial: 'messages/message',
  locals: { message: message }
)
```

For Rails <= 4.2, this functionality can be backported with the [backport_new_renderer gem](https://github.com/brainopia/backport_new_renderer).

Comment: The "easier solution" works but does not provide access to functions like "link_to" that are commonly used in templates.  Neither solution seems to provide access to application-specific helpers.

Comment: @JeremyBurton You could give [`render_anywhere`](https://github.com/yappbox/render_anywhere) a try and see if helpers can be included there.

Comment: I actually solved the problem by simply including the helper modules I needed in the ViewRenderer class. Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyBurton did you include asset helpers (for js, css, public)?  Can you give a code example of that?

Comment: @riley Did you try the [`render_anywhere`](https://github.com/yappbox/render_anywhere) gem?

Comment: @ThomasKlemm yes I have tried it.  It works to a degree, but I have to manually set full file system paths for js, css, and image files.  Additionally it won't render partials relative to the main template ie if I render /myitems/mytemplate and my template calls partials I have to give full view path to each partial.  Was hoping for a way around doing things manually since I have dozens of partials.  I tried the ViewRenderer of yours, and other solutions online, and they all seem to have these issues in common. Unless I'm missing some important config?

Comment: This workaround seems to work with relative paths, but not with assets:

https://gist.github.com/juggy/977181

Comment: @JeremyBurton I agree, if the template has `link_to` it will throw this error: `ActionView::Template::Error: arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation` How did you get around this?

Comment: Thanks for the Update 3! [backport_new_renderer](https://github.com/brainopia/backport_new_renderer) gem is working wonderfully and provides the simplest Rails 5 update option too.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're loading the rails environment in the job. If that is already done you can try something like:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Comment: For Engine URL helpers, that's `MyEngine::Engine.app.url_helpers` (rails 4)