# Rails 6 - write rendered content from erb template to model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Message model which is a sort of crude messaging system.  The Message model has a text attribute named :body which obviously stores the content of the message in html format.

What I'd like to do is trigger a new message using callbacks in other models and populate the :body attribute with rendered content from an erb template.

So for example:

```
Class Assignment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user

  after_create :send_message_to_user

  def send_message_to_user
    Message.create!(recipient: user, body: ("html content here I guess"))
  end

end
```

How would one do this in rails?

Comment: Where do you get the "content from an erb template" from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `render` like this:

```
def send_message_to_user
  Message.create!(
    recipient: user, 
    body: ApplicationController.render 'templates/name',
  )
end
```

Inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42924760/8352929